# Error: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am having the error in the title while I am running this. I am trying to get the first paragraph parsed without any html while running this

**HTML**

```
<div id="headingWiki_0"><h3><span>Roman empire</span></h3></div>
```

**JS**

```
var titolo = $("#headingWiki_0 h3 span").text();
  $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&callback=?", {
    page: titolo
  }, function(data) {
    var markupt = data.parse.text["*"];
    var blurbt = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
    blurbt.find(".mw-editsection, #toc, .noprint, .thumb, img, table").remove();
    // remove links as they will not work
    blurbt.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
    // remove any references
    blurbt.find('sup').remove();
    // remove cite error
    blurbt.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
    $('#usp-custom-4').val($(blurbt).find('p'));

  });
```

Console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Comment: Show the markup you have ... and I guess you need a dot in this rule `$(".headingWiki_0 h3 span").text();`, for the `headingWiki_0`, as it appears to be a class,  not an element

Comment: @LGSon which mark up exactly?

Comment: @rob.m html markup you search inside

Comment: Yep, only two places that `.text` is referred to-- either `$("headingWiki_0 h3 span")` isn't returning anything or your data return from the `$.getJson` doesn't contain a `parse` property.

Comment: After the edit the selector should now work properly, any other error?

Comment: @LGSon no still having the issue, will check now for the value of that variable to see what it gives me

Comment: It is this line that errors: `var markupt = data.parse.text["*"];`

Comment: If you check the `data` variable you'll see what's wrong

Comment: @LGSon still not working :(

Comment: @LGSon check my answer below, thanks

Comment: Glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the I got from another [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891214/how-to-get-the-first-parsed-paragraph-of-wikipedia), this is the code which works

```js
$("#wiki").on("click", function(){
 firstWiki();
});


function onSuccess(data){
      var markupt = data.parse.text["*"];
      $('#usp-custom-4').text(markupt);
      console.log(markupt);
      var blurbt = $('<div></div>').html(markupt);
      blurbt.find(".mw-editsection, #toc, .noprint, .thumb, img, table").remove();
      // remove links as they will not work
      blurbt.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
      // remove any references
      blurbt.find('sup').remove();
      // remove cite error
      blurbt.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
      var pOnly  = $(blurbt).find('p').text();
}

function firstWiki() {
  var titolo = $("#headingWiki_0 h3 span").text();
  titolo = encodeURIComponent(titolo);
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=" + titolo + "&callback=?",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: onSuccess
  });
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  border: 10px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headingWiki_0"><h3><span>Impero romano</span></h3></div>
<button id="wiki">
Load
</button>
<textarea id="usp-custom-4"></textarea>
```

```js
$("#wiki").on("click", function(){
 firstWiki();
});


function onSuccess(data){
      var markupt = data.parse.text["*"];
      console.log(markupt);
      var blurbt = $('<div></div>').html(markupt);
      blurbt.find(".mw-editsection, #toc, .noprint, .thumb, img, table").remove();
      // remove links as they will not work
      blurbt.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
      // remove any references
      blurbt.find('sup').remove();
      // remove cite error
      blurbt.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
      var pOnly  = $(blurbt).find('p').text();
      $('#usp-custom-4').text(pOnly);
}

function firstWiki() {
  var titolo = $("#headingWiki_0 h3 span").text();
  titolo = encodeURIComponent(titolo);
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=" + titolo + "&callback=?",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: onSuccess
  });
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  border: 10px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headingWiki_0"><h3><span>Impero romano</span></h3></div>
<button id="wiki">
Load
</button>
<textarea id="usp-custom-4"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `&callback=?`from the url. It should look like:

`https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=titolo`

The url you use does not return a JSON, but this one should do.

If you have CORS problems, than you should make JSONP requests:

```
function onSuccess(data){
    var markupt = data.parse.text["*"];
    var blurbt = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
    blurbt.find(".mw-editsection, #toc, .noprint, .thumb, img, table").remove();
    // remove links as they will not work
    blurbt.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
    // remove any references
    blurbt.find('sup').remove();
    // remove cite error
    blurbt.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
    $('#usp-custom-4').val($(blurbt).find('p'));
}

$.ajax({
    url: "https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=titolo",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "onSuccess"
})
```

Comment: where do you give the page name then? And this will cause access-control-allow-origin error btw

Comment: You can pass it as a query param. I updated the answer.

Comment: ok starting to look better, yet the $('#usp-custom-4').val is getting [object Object]

Comment: You should use debug further to see where is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138476/discussion-between-rob-m-and-caisah).

Comment: check the answer below