# How to get the first parsed paragraph of wikipedia?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia

This is the **js** I am using:

```
function onSuccess(data){
      var markupt = data.parse.text["*"];
      $('#usp-custom-4').val(markupt);
      console.log(markupt);
      var blurbt = $('<div></div>').html(markupt);
      blurbt.find(".mw-editsection, #toc, .noprint, .thumb, img, table").remove();
      // remove links as they will not work
      blurbt.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
      // remove any references
      blurbt.find('sup').remove();
      // remove cite error
      blurbt.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
      var pOnly  = $(blurbt).find('p').text();
    }

    function firstWiki() {
      var titolo = $("#headingWiki_0 h3 span").text();
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0",
        page: titolo,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "onSuccess"
      });
    }
```

And the **html**

```
<div id="headingWiki_0"><h3><span>Roman empire</span></h3></div>
<button id="wiki">Load</button>
<textarea id="usp-custom-4"></textarea>
```

Here it is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9myz270/4/)

I am getting no content into the textarea at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few adjustments I made to the code and I got it to work (you can see the new fiddle below.

1. I added the `page` parameter to the URL. It wasn't added so far so your initial fiddle was getting an error response from Wikipedia. This meant that there was no article text to work with in the first place. I also uri-encoded it.
2. I changed the way that the JsonP callback was being specified. jQuery was correctly adding the `callback` parameter to the URL and the Wikipedia result was correctly returning a call to it, but it wouldn't get executed. Using `callback=?` and letting jQuery handle the callback by using the `success` option did the trick.
3. I switched `Roman Empire` for `Impero romano`, which is the article that you'll find in the IT version of Wikipedia.
4. I switched `val` for `text`. In the case of textareas, they don't hold `value` as other inputs, but rather text content. I know, inconsistent.

```js
$("#wiki").on("click", function(){
 firstWiki();
});


function onSuccess(data){
      var markupt = data.parse.text["*"];
      $('#usp-custom-4').text(markupt);
      console.log(markupt);
      var blurbt = $('<div></div>').html(markupt);
      blurbt.find(".mw-editsection, #toc, .noprint, .thumb, img, table").remove();
      // remove links as they will not work
      blurbt.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
      // remove any references
      blurbt.find('sup').remove();
      // remove cite error
      blurbt.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
      var pOnly  = $(blurbt).find('p').text();
}

function firstWiki() {
  var titolo = $("#headingWiki_0 h3 span").text();
  titolo = encodeURIComponent(titolo);
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=" + titolo + "&callback=?",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: onSuccess
  });
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  border: 10px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headingWiki_0"><h3><span>Impero romano</span></h3></div>
<button id="wiki">
Load
</button>
<textarea id="usp-custom-4"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! The only thing is that we are now having all the wikipedia article with html too into the textarea, i was more trying to get only the first section and plain text

Comment: ok got it! We need to do       $('#usp-custom-4').text(pOnly);

Comment: @rob.m Awesome! Sorry I didn't get to answer in time, but it's even better that you figured it out! :)